# Obtaining the maximum cost path in a directed, cyclic graph

Tags: routes, graph, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

I am looking for an algorithm that, given a directed cyclic graph (these are the nodes extracted from an OSM map), calculates the path from the starting node A to the ending node B that has the highest cost (in this case elevation difference) within the graph(without going over the same point twice of course). So I want the path with the maximum Cumulative elevation gain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_elevation_gain).
There must not be another path from A to B that has a greater difference in elevation, so I am looking for the optimal solution.
By extracting only a portion of the map the search is limited to it(a few thousand nodes).
I specify that the cost would simply be *NextNode.elevation - CurrentNode.elevation*.

I give an example of edge representation:
['A', 'B', 6] //from a to b there is +6 meters of elevation
['B', 'A', -6] //obviously from b to a there will be a loss of elevation (-6m), that is, a descent
['B', 'D', 4]
['D', 'B', -4]
...etc.

I have already tried a multitude of algorithms such as dijkstra, bellman-ford, A* making perhaps the weights all greater than 0, I have used various structures such as link lists or matrices to "accommodate" the various algorithms but they have not yielded the expected result.

Finally, there are algorithms that actually and in instantaneous times find the best path from A to B with the absolute least elevation gain, so almost no climbs. How is it possible to get the **exact opposite** from these algorithms?

I provide graphic examples to explain what I want:
(*The numbers in blue represent the total cost up to the travel of that specific edge!*)

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozWeb.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pysgY.png)

As you can see, the problem is very similar to the search for the longest route, and also as I anticipate, descents are counted as cost 0...

Comment: If the cost is defined as `NextNode.elevation - CurrentNode.elevation`, then there is no way you can get different total costs from going from A to B. Whichever path you choose, the sum of the costs would always be equal to `B.elevation - A.elevation`. Can you clarify? Do you maybe mean with "IN ABSOLUTE" that the cost is actually `|NextNode.elevation - CurrentNode.elevation|`?

Comment: Example: 
If I have the costs [+6, -3, +7, +0, -4, +1,+2, -5], the accumulation of absolute elevation sum is 16.
Thank you.

Comment: It was just to give a little more context to the commenters and not make the request too long. Anyway agreed, I improve the question by removing the confusing terms.

Comment: You can make the question as long as you need.  You do need to minimize the number of comments.

Comment: -added examples

Answer (score 0):

- Search the data for the link that has the largest absolute change in elevation L.
- Set the weight of each link to be the L - actual absolute change in elevation
- Apply Dijkstra to find the "cheapest" path from A to B.

**Example**

L = 13

Actual link elevation change 5

Link weight for Dijkstra 13 - | 5 | = 8

Actual link elevation change -5

Link weight for Dijkstra 13 - | -5 | = 8

Comment: Hmm, this is new to me. I'm not clear on one thing:
for example if I have the link with VARIATION(so difference of elevation and not the elevation) absolute maximum ['F', 'J', 13],
how will I change the weight of these two links?
['C', 'D', 5],
['D', 'C', -5],  
Do I have to flatting them first?
That is:
['C', 'D', 10],
['D', 'C', 0]

Thank you!

Comment: @PerfectRide Added example worked out in detail

Comment: Okay, but by doing so you are not going to distinguish the ascent from the descent since they have the same cost! That's why I was thinking about flattening...

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to maximize the total change in altitude, whether up or down.  If this is not the case, then you must clarify your question

Comment: To avoid further misunderstanding, I will quote in the question the source that perfectly explains the desired value (maximum Cumulative elevation gain).

Comment: -added examples @ravenspoint